# When using Windows remote desktop, I am unable to see the same interface (Linux PC)

Tags: system-installation, remote-desktop, tightvncserver

Here is the original interface I see in the Linux PC:

[image: original interface in the Linux PC]

And here is the interface I see when accessing the Linux PC through remote desktop:

[image: interface accessing the Linux PC through remote desktop]

I'm having difficulty to get the same interface when accessing through
remote desktop.

[image]

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you running? A must read https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.  Just a heads-up that you have this tagged [tag:windows-subsystem-for-linux], which is a feature of Windows that allows you to run Ubuntu under Windows.  Your question does not appear to be about WSL, but rather RDP.  I've removed the tag for you, but if you really are using WSL, please rollback my change, but also edit your question to explain your configuration, including WSL.  Thanks!